# How can I send the value from c++ to Atmega128A that use RS232 communication?

Tags: c, atmega

I created a program that claculate the distance when a ball is thrown. The formula is as follows.

```
d = (2 * V0 * V0 * sin(pi * seta / 180) * cos(pi * seta / 180)) / g;
```

I want to implement the distance-dependent behavior by sending the distances calculated above to the ATmega128A. For example, When the calculated equation is 1m, 3 LEds are turned on. or when 2m, 5 LEDs are turned on. What should i do?

Comment: Do you have hardware to do this? I mean do you want to send this value from PC to uC via RS232 cable?

Answer (score 0):

i assume your distance calculation is calculated at windows PC and you want to send the calculated value to Atmega128A. Assume both is written in C. You can refer to following link

Atemag128 UART Reference

[UART Programming with Atmega128](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/UART_Programming_with_Atmega128)

Window Serial Reference

[Example serial code for Windows in C](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J73/15.6)